# I want to pretty print an org.w3c.dom.Document without a schema

Tags: java, xml, dom, pretty-print

i feel i'm going mad. I want to pretty print an org.w3c.dom.Document without a schema (in Java). Indentation is not all that i need, i want useless empty lines and whitespaces ignored. Somehow this doesn't happen, every time i parse an XML from a file or write it back to a file there are text nodes containing whitespace in the DOM document(\n, spaces, etc). Isn't there a way that i can get rid of these simply, without a schema and without transforming the XML myself by iterating over all the nodes and removing the empty text nodes?

Example: my input file looks like this (but with a lot more empty lines :)

```
<mytag>
       <anothertag>content</anothertag>



</mytag>
```

I would like my output file to look like this:

```
<mytag>
  <anothertag>content</anothertag>
</mytag>
```

Note: i don't have a schema for the XML (so i'm forced to call builder.setValidating(false)) and i don't have the luxury of an internet connection when this code is run.

Thanks!

**UPDATE**: i found something very close to what i need and maybe it helps other soldiers fighting against XML documents without schemas:

```
org.apache.axis.utils.XMLUtils.normalize(document);
```

Source code [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.axis/axis/1.4/org/apache/axis/utils/XMLUtils.java#XMLUtils.normalize%28org.w3c.dom.Node%29). Calling this after the Document is created and before it's written with a Transformer will produce the pretty output with absolutely no schema validation. JB Nizet also gave me a working answer but i have the feeling some validation is going on behind the scenes of that code which would make it different than my use case. I leave the question open for a few days though in case someone has an even better solution.

Comment: I fail to see how you could have both indentation, and no white space. Could you provide example input and output?

Comment: I just edited the question to show what i'm looking for... To be even more detailed: i'm parsing the input with a DocumentBuilderFactory on which i can't set a schema (therefore the ignoring of whitespace doesn't work and text nodes with whitespaces are created)

Answer (score 4):

Here's a working example:

```
public class Xml {
    private static final String XML =
        "<mytag>\n" +
        "        <anothertag>content</anothertag>\n" +
        "\n" +
        "\n" +
        "\n" +
        "</mytag>";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParserConfigurationException, IOException, SAXException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, ClassNotFoundException {
        DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        documentBuilderFactory.setValidating(false);
        DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document document = documentBuilder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(XML)));

        NodeList childNodes = document.getDocumentElement().getChildNodes();
        for (int i = 0; i < childNodes.getLength(); i++) {
           System.out.println(childNodes.item(i));
        }

        final DOMImplementationRegistry registry = DOMImplementationRegistry.newInstance();
        final DOMImplementationLS impl = (DOMImplementationLS) registry.getDOMImplementation("LS");
        final LSSerializer writer = impl.createLSSerializer();

        writer.getDomConfig().setParameter("xml-declaration", false);
        writer.getDomConfig().setParameter("format-pretty-print", Boolean.TRUE);

        System.out.println(writer.writeToString(document));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[#text: 
        ]
[anothertag: null]
[#text: 



]
<mytag>
    <anothertag>content</anothertag>
</mytag>
```

So, the parser doesn't validate, it preserves the text nodes, and the output produced by the serializer is as you expect it.

Comment: This is validating against a schema (and connecting to the internet :) - it's using HttpUrlConnection) so it's not good for my case. I'm looking for something that ignores whitespace without a schema.

Comment: I have no idea what that means. I suck at XML, frankly. But the above code takes the example input you provided, and produces the output you expect. I have just run the code without any connection available, and it runs fine. And I doubt that the serialization validates anything. If something validates, it must be the parsing, isn't it? And the parsing isn't the problem.

Comment: It validates during the parsing
 at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1300)...
org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)

Comment: Then it's not a problem. You asked how to serialize a DOM document, and the parsing part of my answer is thus irrelevant. You already have a DOM document.

Comment: I want some standard way that removes the useless text nodes. If it happens before, during or after the parsing or serializing it doesn't matter to me. Your answer isn't suitable to me because i don't have the luxury of an internet connection (or of a schema as well) when my code is run. I suspect in your case it's connecting to the internet because the validation flag is still set on the DocumentBuilderFactory and the default entity resolver is set on the builder.

Comment: You said "I want to pretty print an org.w3c.dom.Document". So you already have a Document. Just disregard the parsing part of my answer. Just use the part that serializes the document.

Comment: The serializing part that you mentioned doesn't produce the expected result with a DOM document that already contains the nasty whitespace. I have just confirmed this on my test xml files... Simply because, with this code, with no validation during parsing there is no part in the process that takes out the useless whitespace. Your code works because you don't call setValidating(false) (which i'm forced to call because i don't have a schema) and because you don't change the builder's default entity resolver which connects to the internet.

Comment: Can you please put a breakpoint in your HttpURLConnection.getInputStream and confirm that it's not connecting to the internet? I get back exactly the original output, not pretty printed.

Comment: The breakpoint isn't hit. It's hit if I explicitely create a URL, open a connection and call `getInputStream()`. So the breakpoint "works", and the code above doesn't open a connection. I have no cable plugged in my laptop, and I tested the code with disabled wifi, and it works fine. Oracle JDK 1.7.0_45, on MacOS X.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your time... well, something must be very weird then because the 'malformed' document is not pretty printed in my case :) To be fair i will +1 your answer but in the mean time i'll post another answer which i found in the mean time and i think is more suitable in my case.